# Histogram Equalization In VHDL

Tags: arrays, matrix, vhdl

This code is simply for 4x4 elements.
No Synthesizing.
Even a small initial portion is not simulating

```
     library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
use work.mypackage.ALL;

entity histo_two is
port( H_c: out hist_array);
end histo_two;
architecture Behavioral of histo_two is

constant my_hist:hist_array:=((0,1,2,3), (0, 2, 2, 0), (3, 3, 1, 3), (2, 3, 0, 2));

begin
p0: process
variable h: h_vector:= (0,0,0,0);
variable gp: integer;
variable temp: integer;
variable H_c: h_vector;
variable A: integer;
variable T: h_vector;

for i in my_hist'left(1) to my_hist'right(1) loop
for j in my_hist'left(2) to my_hist'right(2) loop
gp := my_hist(i,j);

temp:= h(gp) + 1;
h(gp) := temp;
end loop;
end loop;
-- Form the cumulative image histogram Hc:
H_c(0) := H(0);
for p in h'left(1)+1 to h'right(1) loop
A := H_c(p-1) + H(p);
H_c(p) := A;
end loop;

end process;
end behavioral;
```

These are my warnings. This is a part of my big module.

Output should be H: 4,2,5,5(this is internal signal value) and H_c:(4,6,11,16)

```
  No sensitivity list and no wait in the process
WARNING:Xst:1306 - Output <H_c<1>> is never assigned.
WARNING:Xst:1306 - Output <H_c<2>> is never assigned.
WARNING:Xst:1306 - Output <H_c<3>> is never assigned.
WARNING:Xst:1306 - Output <H_c<0>> is never assigned.
```

Package File

```
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
```

Package 
        package mypackage is

```
            type hist_array is array (0 to 3,0 to 3) of integer;
            type h_vector is array (0 to 3) of integer;       


    end mypackage;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're code example doesn't analyze. There's an extra reserved word `Package` in the package declaration and a missing process statement begin. Also as noted in your Xilinx Synthesis Technology warnings the process has no wait statement and no sensitivity list. With no input ports there's nothing for a sensitivity list so a wait statement is in order. You also never assign the variables the warnings note. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Please indent and format your code, so we can read it.

Answer (score 2):

1. To get your your to analyze The first line of the package declaration:

   Package package mypackage is

becomes:

```
package mypackage is
```

(Note your code isn't formatted correctly in your question.)

2. Your P0 process is missing a `begin`:

The first sequential statement (the first for loop):

```
p0: process
variable h: h_vector:= (0,0,0,0);
variable gp: integer;
variable temp: integer;
variable H_c: h_vector;
variable A: integer;
variable T: h_vector;

for i in my_hist'left(1) to my_hist'right(1) loop
for j in my_hist'left(2) to my_hist'right(2) loop
```

should be preceded by `begin`:

```
p0: 
    process
        variable h: h_vector:= (0,0,0,0);
        variable gp: integer;
        variable temp: integer;
        variable H_c: h_vector;
        variable A: integer;
        variable T: h_vector;
    begin
        for i in my_hist'left(1) to my_hist'right(1) loop
            for j in my_hist'left(2) to my_hist'right(2) loop
```

A wait state is added to allow the process to suspend, the simulation time be advanced to time'HIGH and the simulation to finish:

```
end process;
end behavioral;
```

Added `wait`:

```
        wait;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

Adding two report statements before the added wait statement when simulated gives

> ghdl -r histo_two
>   histo_two.vhdl:45:9:@0ms:(report note): h = ( 4, 2, 5, 5)
>    histo_two.vhdl:50:9:@0ms:(report note): H_c = ( 4, 6, 11, 16)

So All you are missing is the process begin, a wait statement in the process and a proper code example for the package.

The standard (IEEE Std 1076-2008) describes a package declaration in 4.7 Package declarations.

Process statements in 11.3 Process statement, the requirement for the `begin` in the BNF (which is normative outside Appendix C). See paragraph 4 for the implicit wait statement based on the sensitivity list.

A process suspends and resumes in wait statements, otherwise they'll capture thread execution during simulation.  Some VHDL simulators may object to processes without an explicit or implicit wait statement.

How a wait statement is constructed from a sensitivity list and what a wait statement does is also addressed in 10.2 Wait statement and how it effects simulation in 14.7.5 Model execution.

Report statements are described in 10.4 Report statements and generally become useful with a knowledge of attribute usage (see 16.2 Predefined attributes).

Two of these three errors are basic syntax problems (The two `Package package` reserved words is a question formatting error), the missing `begin` is purely a syntax error. The lack of a sensitivity list or wait statement is a VHDL authoring error.

These are basic VHDL coding errors.

Comment: Sir, I went through your suggestions.Thanks a lot! Can u please modify

Comment: 'Can u modify' what?

Comment: means what changes i need to make in this! Some of the suggestions u made i cannot get. If possible an example u may suggest! Thank u Sir..